# Extrat data from rest post node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request

I use the request library to develop service post:

```
var request = require('request');

request.post(
    'http://localhost:3000/carica',
    { json: { id: "", input: 52, rfid:"M2" } },
    function (error, response, body) { 
            console.log(body)
    }
);
```

The question is the following: how can I extrat this data in my server? I want to handle the information not as json object but as string(for the field rfid) or as numeric type(for the field input).

Comment: your server is nodejs right ?

Comment: Yes is nodejs,it is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032785/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-on-node-js

Comment: you are receiving `post` requests on your server and you want to get the data in request body. is that what you're trying to achieve

Comment: yes exactly,sorry if the answer wasn't clear